# $readmemh syntax error for .mif file in Verilog HDL Intel Quartus Prime

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

I am trying to read a `.mif` file and this is the error I am getting -

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at sine3_test1.MIF **near
> text: p**. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately
> before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database
> contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this
> error. Visit the Knowledge Database at
> https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html
> and search for this specific error message number.

The error seems to be in first line.
My MIF file has 8-bit data width and 256 words depth.

```
memory address = UNS (unisgned decimal)
memory data = hexadecimal
```

[image]

My source code is the following:

```
reg [7:0]memory[0:255];
begin
    $readmemh("sine3_test1.MIF",memory);
end
```

I removed white spaces and added a few missing memory block numbers.
Currently, I have it stored in my project folder (although not part of the Quartus project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the input file is incorrect for `$readmemh`.  The `$readmemh` system task expects a file to just have numbers in hexadecimal format, not words like `DEPTH`, or address/data pairs like `0:78;`.

You can not directly read the `mif` file using `$readmemh`.  You need to create another file with just the data in it, like `sine3_test1.hex`:

```
78
7a
7d
```

Then use:

```
$readmemh("sine3_test1.hex", memory);
```

For the complete specification of the input file format, refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.4 *Loading memory array data from a file*.  The format does support address information, but it does not seem necessary in this case.

---

You could read the `mif` file using `$fopen` (and related functions) instead of `$readmemh`, but that would be a lot more work.